# Any integer input except one with "6" as the right-most digit works, but any number like ...6 leads to segmentation fault, why?

Tags: c++

My C++ program named "coinChange.cpp" reports the number of notes of different figures for changing a given integer amount. The code is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     cout<<"please enter the amount: ";
     int amount;
     cin>>amount;
     int totalNoOfCoins=0;
     int coins[]= {100,50,20,10,5,1};
     int noOfCoins[sizeof(coins)]= {0};
     int counter=0;
     while(amount>0)
     {
          if(amount>coins[counter])
          {
                noOfCoins[counter]=amount/coins[counter];
                amount-=noOfCoins[counter]*coins[counter];
          }
          counter++;
     }
     string output="The amount can be changed by:\n";
     for(int i=0;i<sizeof(coins);i++)
     {
         if(noOfCoins[i]>0)
         {
             ostringstream oss;
             ostringstream oss1;
             oss<<coins[i];
             oss1<<noOfCoins[i];
            if(noOfCoins[i]>1) output+="\t\t\t"+oss1.str()+" nos of "+oss.str()+" taka notes \n";
            else output+="\t\t\t"+oss1.str()+" no of "+oss.str()+" taka note \n";
          }
    }
    cout<<output<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is okay for almost any integers like 34, 37829, ... etc, but the problem arises when the user inputs a number that ends in 6 like 6, x6, xx6, xxx6 etc.

Comment: Start by running your program in a debugger to find out *where* (in your code) the crash happens.

Comment: Also, you might want to look at this loop: `for(int i=0;i<sizeof(coins);i++)`. The `sizeof` operator returns the size of the array *in bytes* and not the number of entries.

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 issues I see with your code.

First, the obvious one:

**You are misusing `sizeof`**:

```
 int noOfCoins[sizeof(coins)]= {0};
```

This should be:

```
 const int numCoins = sizeof(coins) / sizeof(coins[0]);
 int noOfCoins[numCoins]= {0};
```

Then from there, you can use `numCoins` for the rest of the code:

```
 for(int i=0;i < numCoins; i++)
```

The reason why `sizeof(coins)` did not work is that `sizeof` returns the size *in bytes*.

So if you have an array of 6 `int`s, the `sizeof` the array is `sizeof(int) * 6`, which is (assuming you are using 4 byte integers), 24.  That goes way beyond the bounds of your array, thus you get undefined behavior.

---

**Second issue: Faulty while() loop condition**:

In the `while` loop condition, you're only testing for `amount > 0`.  But what if amount is a large value?  Your `while` loop will increment `counter` to beyond the bounds of your array, and you will be using `counter` as an index in your `coins` array, thus accessing beyond the bounds of the array.

The while loop should have this condition:

`while (amount > 0 && counter < numCoins)`

---

**Third issue: Faulty test logic for the right coinage amount**

You do this:

```
if (amount > coins[counter])
```

But this is wrong.  What if the amount entered is simply `100`?  You miss the check for the 100 note using the above condition.  This simply needs to be changed to this:

```
if (amount >= coins[counter])
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but the output is same as before, i.e., it is working for all inputs except the ones ending with 6, there must be problems in anywhere else, I need help...

Comment: You have a `while` loop that goes haywire for input such as`123456`.  The condition should be `(amount > 0 && counter < 6)`.  If you're going to increment `counter`, and `counter` is used as an array index, you better make sure it's a valid index.  Also, please run your code using a debugger -- the error that I just pointed out to you in the comment would have been obvious if you did that.

Comment: That should be `(amount > 0 && counter < numCoins)` given that you set `numCoins` to the value I gave as an answer.

Comment: @anik_sbl Please see the updated answers.  They discuss all 3 items in your code that are wrong.

Comment: thanks everybody, life is so beautiful as great people like you are all around to take care of the issues that go beyond my feat...thanksss...

Comment: @anik_sbl - If this answer corrects the error, make sure you mark it as correct.